# How to use NoCloud Cloud-init to install Ubuntu 20.04 Live Server from a USB stick?

Tags: server, automation, cloud-init

I'm trying to automatically provision my own Ubuntu server (mobo is X570 AORUS PRO), in the end I'm hoping that I could just plug in a USB stick and restart the machine for installation to begin.

I found [this](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources/nocloud.html) , and I thought this could be as simple as using another USB stick that has the label "cidata" and contains `user-data` and `meta-data` files. But it seems that the installation ignores it or cannot detect it.

Do I need to do further modifications to the installer before flashing it? e.g. where does this part have to be embedded?

```
ds=nocloud[;key=val;key=val]
```

And is it possible to eliminate the additional USB?

Answer (score 2):

I'm experimenting as well these days and was looking for the same solution.

You can follow [this gist](https://gist.github.com/s3rj1k/55b10cd20f31542046018fcce32f103e), it is pretty well documented. However, getting dynamic (i.e. changing at every install) `user-data` from USB is not as simple. This is because, cloud-init does have the volume mounted when it attempts to retrieve the config. It might be easier to go with nocloud-net and serve the file via a docker container or via NAS shared folder.